# I am trying to get price field values from database .getting error #message: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

this is my controller

```
public function productsCategorywise(Request $request,$catslug)
    {
        try{
            $category_id = $request->catslug;
            $subCategories = SubCategory::with('childrenCategories')->where('parent','=', '2')->get();

            $subproducts = ProductsMeta::where('meta_value',$category_id)
                ->where('meta_key','term_taxonomy_id')
               ->get();

            $array_data = [];
            foreach ($subproducts as $key => $value) {
                $post_id = $value->post_id;
                $getProducts = Products::with('productMeta')->where('id',$post_id)->first();
                array_push($array_data, $getProducts);
            }
            if(isset($array_data) && !empty($array_data)){
                return view('backEnd.products',compact('array_data','subCategories','getProducts'));
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return $e;
     }

//this is my view page
                            
                                                <div class="product_price">
                                                     @foreach($value->productMeta as $m)
                                                          @if($m['meta_key'] == 'regular_price')
                                                              <?php
                                                              $metaVal = $m['meta_value']; ?>
                                                              <?php
                                                              $metavalueArray = explode(',',$metaVal);
                                                              ?>
                                                              @foreach($metavalueArray as $key => $v)
                                                                  <span class="price" {{$v}}></span>
                                                              @endforeach
                                                          @endif
                                                    @endforeach

                                                    <del>(display regular price)</del>
                                                    <div class="on_sale">
                                                        <span>35% Off</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

there are two tables product and productmeta
I need to fetch meta_key and meta_value from productmeta table to show  meta_value for regular_price which stores multiple values
$value is not able to get the array values for regular_price
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because you are trying to access `$m['meta_key']` when `$m` is *null*.

Try using `{{ dd($m) }}` right under the "foreach" does it output the value you expect?

Comment: #message: "Trying to get property of non-object".
I am getting this error when looping in foreach for $value .